# Configurable Product showed twice

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

```
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); 
$_product = $model->load($product_id); 
$stocklevel = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
                ->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty();
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);//get order id
    $items = $order->getItemsCollection();
    foreach($items as $i){ 
    $product_id = $i->product_id;
    $_product = $model->load($product_id); 
    $stocklevel = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
            ->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty();
    $product_sku = $i->getsku();
    $product_name = $i->getName();
    $quantity_ordered = round($i->getqty_ordered());
    if($stocklevel==0)
    {
    $product_detail.="<table><tr style='color:red;'><td >".$product_sku. "</td><td>".$quantity_ordered."X".$product_name."</td></tr></table>";
    }
    else
    {
        $product_detail.="<table><tr><td>".$product_sku. "</td><td>".$quantity_ordered."X".$product_name."</td></tr></table>";

    }
    }
    return $product_detail;
```

it show configurable product 2 times [image]

Comment: You are getting **product id**  from order item. there is two different item from same configure  product. That's why it is coming twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you used `$items = $order->getItemsCollection();` to get list of ordered items.

There are other function also available to get ordered items.

1. getAllItems()
2. getAllVisibleItems()

Whats the difference is

```
public function getAllItems() {
    $items = array();
    foreach ($this->getItemsCollection() as $item) {
       if (!$item->isDeleted()) {
          $items[] = $item;
       }
    }
    return $items;
}

public function getAllVisibleItems() {
    $items = array();
    foreach ($this->getItemsCollection() as $item) {
       if (!$item->isDeleted() && !$item->getParentItemId()) {
          $items[] = $item;
      }
    }
    return $items;
}
```

The only difference is getAllVisibleItems() has an additional check to search for parent ID.

```
if (!$item->isDeleted() && !$item->getParentItemId()) {
```

**getAllVisibleItems** will show you only the parent item while **getAllItem** will show both products. so please update your code by using **getAllItem**